# let $X$ be any set. and $f,g: X \to X$ are maps which are not one one. Can $fog\ $ be one one map ??

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

let $X$ be any set. and $f,g: X \to X$ are maps which are not one to one.

Can $f \circ g\ $ be one to one map  ??

I think it cannot be one to one but I'm not sure how to prove that. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : can you prove the following general result : if $f: X\to Y, g:Y\to Z$ and $g\circ f$ is injective, then so is $f$ ?

Comment: .yes i got this .Thanks